# Can Keys of Dictionary be instances of a class?

Tags: python

Lets assume I have a `class a`which has the function `__eq__(self,other)`. Now I want to have a dictionary where the keys are instances of the class (and the values numbers, but that should not make a difference). Then I get the error:

```
unhashable type: 'a'
```

In the documenation it says that I should define `__eq__` and `__cmp__` in order to define `__hash__`, but that is not possible since my class is not comparable!!

How to solve this, folks!

edit: Ok I made it works with only a  **_*eq*_** and **_*hash*_** method, but I am still not sure if python uses the hash method in the **in** operation or the **_*eq*_** method (which should be the case I hope)

Comment: def __hash__(self): return hash(self.value ^ 31 & 15)

Comment: what should self.value be? The class is supposed to be abstract!

Comment: @varantir You could just add a dummy print statement to `__hash__` to test if that's the one it's calling.  Also, I suggest you check my answer out to make sure that your hash function is sound.

Answer (score 3):

The [documentation](http://docs.python.org/2/glossary.html) says that beside the `__hash__()` it needs an `__eq__()` **or** (not "and" as you suggest) `__cmp__()` method.

So in your case it is enough to define the `__hash__()` method.

Answer (score 1):

A `class` can be a key for a `dict`, so long as the `hashCode` for the `class` is constant.  If at any point in time that the key, `hashCode`, for the class can change, then you would not be able to use it as a key.

This is precisely why a `list` cannot be used as a key.  An alternative for the `list` would be to use a `tuple` since `tuples` are immutable.  Again, if you can guarantee that the `hashCode` won't change, you're good.

Answer (score 0):

It works for me..

```
>>> class A:
...     def __init__(self):
...             self.a = 5
... 
>>> a = A()
>>> d = { a:"hello"}
>>> d[a]
'hello'
```

You can use class instances as keys for a dict

Comment: *You can use class instances as keys for a dict* - as long as they have a suitable `__hash__` method that is...

Answer (score 0):

This is not a direct answer, but may be it can help you.

You can override `__cmp__` and raise `NotImplementedError` to avoid usage of it.

```
class SomeClass():
    def __init__(self):
        pass  # your init here

    def __cmp__(self, orher):
        raise NotImplementedError('You can not compare this')

    def __eq__(self, other):
        pass  # Your eq here

    def __hash__(self):
        pass  # your hash function here
```

Demo:

```
>> s = SomeClass()
>> s == '12'

>> NotImplementedError: You can not compare this
```